# Mysql orderby hierarchical text, yet sort as a number?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

Yes, the title is confusing, but I will keep this simple. Imagine a photo page and on it are comments. These comments can be nested by replying to them. I need to find the correct sort order for them.

I am storing these hierarchies using a "lineage". It is a textual, flattened value of the position of a single comment in the hierarchy. Here is a correctly sorted thread. I'm only showing the lineage column:

**903

909

909-1404

1405**

903 is the first comment, 909 the second. 1404 is a reply to the second comment, and finally, 1405 is the last comment, a non-reply. This is how they should be sorted. I'm struggling to reach that result though. This is what I get if I simply do this:

ORDER BY lineage

**1405

903

909

909-1404**

The error here is that 1405 should be at the bottom. I know of the (+0) trick to order text like it is a number:

ORDER BY (lineage+0)

Which gives me this:

**903

909-1404

909

1405**

This time, the threaded comment (1404) is wrongly sorted, it should come after the parent (909).

Is there an easy way to accomplish my desired sorting? The only thing I could think of is to fill comment ids with zeroes in front, but that would be an incredibly painful migration process that I desperately want to avoid.

Comment: Convert your text to numbers.  What DB are you using?  cause the only thing I am unsure of is how the dash would be handled.

Comment: That's why I suggest converting the dash to the decimal separator and ordering as decimals (or doubles).

Comment: I'm using MySQL. Casting to numbers (which is the effect of the +0 trick) brings the problem explained in the question. It indeed does not handle the dash right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pad the numbers in lineage with zeros so you can properly order them as strings.

Of course for proper padding you need to know the max number you want to store there.

There are other ways to store hierarchic tree relations (parent links, nested tree sets). Your approach has some benefits for specific tasks, but, as you can see, also has its limits.

Comment: Yes, but padding is what I wanted to avoid. I am hoping for something easier, but that will be the fallback.

Comment: Maybe there's some magic sql transformation that does what you want (*I doubt it*), but the query has to check each element, you won't be able to use indexes for the ordering.

Comment: I eventually went with this solution, padding comment ids to 9 zeroes max. Had to do a data migration but it works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(lineage,"-",".") AS DOUBLE)

903
909
909.1404
1405
```

But your 'lineage' is perhaps not the best way how to store relations between data in a relational database... maybe consider normalizing?

Comment: Very creative solution... I too was thinking of converting to a number, but your - to . as double makes it even easier.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. MySQL does not allow casting to DOUBLE. By the way, this is normalized hierarchical data already. Hierarchical with unlimited nesting.